# Extract element names from a vector within list

Tags: r

I'm building a shiny app and i would like to extract the name of a vector value within a list to use in the plot title.

I have this list with variable names:

```
vars <- list(
  acidentes = c("Veículo" = "veic", "Tipo de acidente" = "tipo_acid",
                "# ciclistas" = "ciclistas"),
  vitimas = c("Sexo" = "sexo", "Idade" = "idade"),
  tempo = c("Ano" = "ano", "Mes" = "mes", "Dia da semana" = "dia_semana",
            "Hora do dia" = "hora_dia", "Período do dia" = "periodo_dia"),
  geo = c("Distritos" = "distritos")
)

vars

$acidentes
Veículo Tipo de acidente      # ciclistas 
"veic"  "tipo_acid"           "ciclistas" 

$vitimas
Sexo   Idade 
"sexo" "idade" 

$tempo
Ano    Mes    Dia da semana  Hora do dia  Período do dia 
"ano"  "mes"  "dia_semana"   "hora_dia"   "periodo_dia" 

$geo
Distritos 
"distritos"
```

Inside shiny, my attempt was:

```
l <- names(vars[vars == input$variavel])
n <- names(vars[[l]])[vars[[l]] == input$variavel]
tit <- paste("Taxa média de fatalidade, por", n)
```

I can't understand why, but this works when my choice is the "distritos" variable, but not with another.

If I run this code outside shiny environment with "distritos" i get this:

```
l <- names(vars[vars == "ano"])
n <- names(vars[[l]])[vars[[l]] == "distritos"]
paste("Taxa média de fatalidade, por", n)
[1] "Taxa média de fatalidade, por Distritos"
```

But if I call another variable, for example "anos", it doesn't works.

```
l <- names(vars[vars == "anos"])
n <- names(vars[[l]])[vars[[l]] == "anos"]
Error in vars[[l]] : attempt to select less than one element in get1index
```

I had tried using `vars[vars == "anos"]` and `vars[vars %in% "anos"]` and the result is the same. Works for "distritos" but not for another variable.

Why is this not working?
Have someone an ideia on how to run this?

Sorry for my english and many thanks, in advance.

Comment: Do you need `unlist(sapply(vars, function(x)  names(x[x == "ano"])))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, @akrun. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a `list` of named `vector`s, we can loop over the `list` with `lapply/sapply` extract the `names` of vector after the comparison and `unlist` the `list` elements to a `vector` (if necessary)

```
unlist(sapply(vars, function(x) names(x[x == "ano"])))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with the "distritos" example because that is only a length 1 character vector - so when you `vars[vars == "distritos"]` it matches the value of that vector.

You need to either check on the names in the list (not the names of each individual character vector) or you need to look at the lower level using something like this:

```
l <- "ano"
names(vars[sapply(vars, function(x) l %in% x)])
```

Comment: This returns "tempo", the name of the vector in which searched value is inside, not the vector element name. The akrun solution is working. Thanks for your help.